# regular expression to match a certain pattern and a certain number of values in between

Tags: java

sorry for the confusing title... I am editng a simple java method of android app that I inherited. Currently it is like this:

```
     String id = "\\border_3_4_5_.*\\b";
```

which matches:

```
        order_3_4_5_anything
```

now I want to update it so match so it can match any of the values 5,6,7,8 instead of just 5 and the rest remains the same.

```
       order_3_4_[5 or 6 or 7 or 8]_
```

I have tried the following:

```
         String id = "\\border_3_4_[5|6|7|8]_.*\\b";
         String id = "\\border_3_4_(5|6|7|8)_.*\\b";
         String id = "\\border_3_4_[5,6,7,8]_.*\\b";
```

but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Why are you using "\\" at the beginning and also "\\b" at the end of the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your requirement properly, it is to match the following inputs,

```java
order_3_4_5_
order_3_4_6_
order_3_4_7_
order_3_4_8_
```

So the appropriate regex for the above would be,

```java
String pattern = "order_3_4_[5|6|7|8]_.*"
```

You have to simply get rid of the "\b" at the beginning and end of the regex. Not quite sure why you have used those backslashes there. The regex you have given would match the following sample inputs,

```
\border_3_4_5_\b
\border_3_4_6_\b
\border_3_4_7_\b
\border_3_4_8_\b
```

This is because in your regex, the "\" is equivalent to a single backslash since the first backslash is to escape the second backslash. Likewise at the end the "\b" is equivalent to a single backlash followed by b, again since the first backslash is to escape the second backslash.

You can test out these regexes [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)

Hope this answer helped you! If it did, i would very much appreciate if you mark my answer as "Accepted". Good day!

Comment: @idi99 thanks. I will try your answer. the \b was there in the code and I don't know what it is doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As @idl99 said I'm not sure about the `\\b`'s but you can use either of those regex patterns:

`order_3_4_(5|6|7|8)_.*`

`order_3_4_[5678]_.*`

`order_3_4_[5-8]_.*`

Sidenote: You can test your regexes here: https://regex101.com/